# Spring Batch fails with Transaction error when triggered by Spring Integration

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I have a simple Spring Boot (2.6.4) app that uses Spring Batch and Spring Integration to read data from a file and emit Kafka events. I have configured Spring Integration to poll a configurable directory and trigger the Spring Batch Job as soon as a new file arrives.

As soon as the Job is "kicked" I get this error:

`Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).`

I assume this is triggered by the following Spring Integration configuration:

```
 return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource,
    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)
          .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
          .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)
          .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory())
          .transactional(new PseudoTransactionManager())))
```

The `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` is configured to move the incoming file into an error or success directory, based on the outcome of the job.
My understanding is that a Spring Batch Job does not like to be executed within the context of a Transaction, since it needs to manage its own transaction to deal with multiple steps failures.

I also understand that I could set the value of `setValidateTransactionState` of  `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` to `false`, but I would rather not mess around with the Spring Batch internals.

As suggested elsewhere, I have also tried to use an Async Job Launcher, but no luck.

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
   SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
   jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
   jobLauncher.setJobRepository(this.jobRepository);
   return jobLauncher;
}
```

The app is using an in-memory H2 data-source, but that doesn't seem to affect the error.

I'm unable to find a solution to this problem, any recommendation?

Edit - full project here: https://github.com/luciano-fiandesio/spring-batch-and-integration-demo

Comment: I found a way to fix the problem, but it feels a bit like a hack. I have created a `AsyncJobLaunchRequestHandler` that uses a Future to launch the job:

`return executor.submit(() -> jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters));`

The `AsyncJobLaunchRequestHandler` is used by the Spring Integration flow.
Do I really need to write my async Job Launcher to avoid running the job in the same transaction as the Integration flow?

Comment: could you please update your project repository with AsyncJobLaunchRequestHandler  usage?